# Rails: How do I install particles.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to implement this on my app but I have no clue how I could install this? Can you post a step by step so that I may understand what files to put where as I've tried to follow the instructions on the github page and got not success.

http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/#default

index.html --> I put code it in *views/layouts/application.html*

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>

<script src="particles.js"></script>
```

---

app.js --> I put it in *assets/javascript/application.js*

```
/* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
  console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

---

particles.json --> I put it in *assets/javascript/application.js*

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 10,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 80,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 300,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 2
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 12,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "repulse"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 800,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 800,
        "size": 80,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 400,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
}
```

Comment: When you say "no success" you should explain what your specific problem is and then someone can advise you.  The best general advice on how to install it is to read the README which you've already done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't set this with the gem, but i made it work with the next steps:

1. Download the Particle.js file, this will give you the JS file and also, the json file which, will be better if you save inside the public folder or better, if you store it inside an a service as Amazon S3.
   So, the first step, is store a copy to the **particles.js** file inside the vendor folder.

   ```
       your_project/vendor/assets/javascripts/particles.js
   ```
2. After that, you need to modify the assets.rb file, which is store inside the **config/initializers/** folder.

   ```
     your_project/config/initializers/assets.rb
     
       Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'javascripts') 
       Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( .js .es6 )
   ```
3. Insert the JSON file inside the public folder or if you can, it's better store it as i told you, in an Amazon S3 service. This will give you a route that will work for us.
4. Go to the main folder and inside the application javascript assets, open the **application.js** file and insert the next changes. This probably can be different in regard to your configuration:

   ```
     //= require jquery
     //= require jquery_ujs
     //= require tether
     //= require bootstrap-sprockets
     //= require turbolinks
     //= require particles
   ```

Remember that you don't need to point to the **vendor** folder when you are using assets on it because we tell to Rails, inside the **assets.rb** file we will also upload some file to this folder.

5. Now, put the running code inside your main layout. I did it inside my **footer.html.erb** file, you can paste it wherever you want.

   ```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'https://s3-##-west-#.amazonaws.com/your_project/particles.json', function() {
       console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
    });
     </script>
   ```

Change the second parameter for which you will use to store the JSON file, and we are almost ready. And also remember, you have to fill it with the configurations you want to display in screen

6. Add the **id** to the element you want to display, for example:

   ```
     <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="particles-js">
   ```

And everything its ready.

Remember run the command in terminal:

```
      rails assets:precompile #in development environment if you want to test it.
```

And run the:

```
      RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile #if you want to run as a production environment.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the `particles.js` file you downloaded into `app/assets/javascripts` and make sure you have something like `require_tree .` in your `application.js`.

You can then safely remove `<script src="particles.js"></script>` from your layout as the script will be loaded by the asset pipeline.