# JS particles injects into param :id (shows locally, not in heroku production)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, particles.js

I have this same issue locally and on production but at least in local, JS particles appears.

This is the git of the code:

```
    <div class="jumbo" id="particles-js"></div>
        <div id="particles-js"></div>
        <script src="particles.js"></script>
...
```

Then i get this same error local and production:

```
Started GET "/listings/particles.js" for xxx at 2019-03-21 21:23:12 -0400
Processing by ListingsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"particles"}
...
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (can't find record with friendly id: "particles"):
```

The issue isn't friednly ID because the same happens with or with out.

Now this error appears no matter what but in local at least the particles show.

What's up with this?

Comment: Where is your `particles.js` file?

Comment: so i have the particles.min.js file in my assets/javascript, but then i have the particles.js file, which is the json file that controls the coloring in my vendor/javascript.  I do not have a require particles in my application.js

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339540/rails-how-do-i-install-particles-js

Comment: @lacostenycoder hm i followed a dif guide tht said to use the .min file. . ill try this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what is happening is that you have a resource called `Listing` which has a route that looks something like this `/listings/:id`.

When that page is rendered the html includes a script tag requesting `particles.js` which is a relative path, so the browser is making a request to `/listings/particles.js`. Rails is interpreting this as a request to the `Listing` resource and looking for a `Listing` with an `id` of `particles` which it cannot find.

To fix this, you have a couple options:

1. require `particles.js` in your [`application.js`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) file by adding the line below. This will include the `particles.js` javascript on every page of your website (that includes `application.js`)

```
//= require particles
```

2. add a [`javascript_include_tag`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets) and include `particles.js` on the single html/erb page. This will only include `particles.js` on the specific view file but will require the user to download a separate Javascript file. To tell the Rails Asset Pipeline to include this file you will need to also modify `config/initializers/assets.rb` to ensure it is precompiled
   In your view:

```rb
<%= javascript_include_tag "particles" %>
```

In `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( particles.js )
```

*Note: If you follow either of these steps, the Rails asset pipeline should minifiy the file for you when deploying to production (so you don't need to use particles.min.js).*

Comment: So it looks like, locally, the issue is `<!-- <script src="particles.js"></script> -->`... testing production

Comment: @uno yeah, if you look at your Rails logs you can see a request is being made to `Started GET "/listings/particles.js"` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, but i don't understand why it would attempt that Get for it just because of a script src? is that how that is supposed to work?

Comment: Yeah, that's an HTML thing. `<script src="particles.js"></script>` is basically saying, make a request to load this script which is located at "particles.js" relative to my current path. So if your current path is `/one/two/three.html` it will look for `/one/two/particles.js`.

Comment: So its working locally, not in production but now the routing issue is gone though.

Comment: As for precompile, I already have `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << '*.js'`

Comment: If you're using the `javascript_include_tag "particles"` make sure you also add `particles.js` to the precomple list: `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( particles.js )` -- I updated my answer with more details.  This basically tells the Rails Asset Pipeline to include that file when it runs (which only happens in production)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190470/discussion-between-scott-bartell-and-uno).